# How spring data jpa mapped split a table?

Tags: mapping, spring-data-jpa

How spring data JPA mapped split a table?
Already, I have an Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_attendance_teacher_result")
@Data
public class AttendanceRecord extends          TimeEntity {
@EmbeddedId
private AttendanceRecordPrimaryKey id;

private int gid;

private String teacherName;
}
```

but now I want to split the table `tbl_attendance_teacher_result` by gid;
table name like 
`tbl_attendance_teacher_result_1`,
`tbl_attendance_teacher_result_2` ...etc.

How should I modify the entity class?

Comment: Can you clarify your question and share what you've already tried?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have modify the description

Comment: Which data should go in which table?

Comment: @JensSchauder if gid eq 1 then insert into tbl_attendance_teacher_result_1,and so on

Comment: Oh, you are partitioning the table. You should do that on in the database itself. How depends on the RDBMS you are using. See for example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm